# How to add HTTP_FORWARDED in logformat in uWSGI

Tags: python, uwsgi, falconframework

I am referring - https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogFormat.html

Default logformat is:

```
[pid: %(pid)|app: -|req: -/-] %(addr) (%(user)) {%(vars) vars in %(pktsize) bytes} [%(ctime)] %(method) %(uri) => generated %(rsize) bytes in %(msecs) msecs (%(proto) %(status)) %(headers) headers in %(hsize) bytes (%(switches) switches on core %(core))
```

`%(addr)` is `REMOTE_ADDR`

My app is behind one reverse proxy. So I need `HTTP_FORWARDED` to get real IP address of the client.

I can see option to configure [user defined logvars](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogFormat.html#user-defined-logvars) but not sure if that doable via **Falcon**.

Answer (score 8):

Add the option `--log-x-forwarded-for` to the uwsgi command, or,
to the *site.ini* as:

```sh
log-x-forwarded-for = true
```

if you are using a config file.

See details in the uwsgi [options](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#log-x-forwarded-for)